# Passing a text field value into popup page using URL

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to pass the value of a text field from one page to another using the URL but failing miserably.

The reason for this is as follows:
I have an apex page which displays a machines properties (make, model, what products it makes, machine ID (:P1_INPUT)). Some machines can only make one product, other can make a variety.

I use a query to complete the following: If the machine only makes one type of product , the product number is displayed in :P1_item. If a machine can make more than one product it displays in :P1_item the world 'multiple'.

I want to build in the ability to click on a button next to :P1_Item, a popup appears with the products the machine makes if ‘multiple’ is displayed. I have the popup bit working but its not passing my :P1_INPUT from the page to the popup page text field :P3_OUPUT
The following code i have on the button, so when it is clicked, it opens a popup page (this works) and should populate the text field (P3_OUTPUT) with the value passed from P1_INPUT (this doesnt work).

My button is set to Redirect to URL and i have this in the URL target.

```
javascript:popupURL('f?p=&APP_ID.:HELLOWORLD:&SESSION.:::&P3_OUTPUT.:&P1_INPUT.')
```

I cant use a branch because i dont want the main page showing the machine properties to submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your URL is wrong: `f?p=&APP_ID.:HELLOWORLD:&SESSION.:::&P3_OUTPUT.:&P1_INPUT.` : you want to provide a value for the item `P3_OUTPUT` while you have set `&P3_OUTPUT.` which is a substitution string and would put the value of `P3_OUTPUT` in the string.
You need to set the URL to `f?p=&APP_ID.:HELLOWORLD:&SESSION.::::P3_OUTPUT:&P1_INPUT.`, which would correctly set the value of `P3_OUTPUT` and add an extra semi-colon between the session identifier and the arguments-values pair.

Comment: When I try that i get back an error: "ERR-1002 Unable to find item ID for item "123" in application "16170".

Unexpected error, unable to find item name at application or page level." 123 is the machine's ID in the text field i am trying to pass. This error appears in the popup window

Comment: Double-check your URL syntax: the last semi-colon is the splitter for item names on the left hand and item values on the right. The error you describe must mean that P3_OUTPUT is still being replaced by a value, which must not happen. Stupid question maybe, but are you sure you removed the `&` and `.` around P3_OUTPUT?

Comment: Yep i removed it, this is what i now have-- javascript:popupURL('f?p=&APP_ID.:HELLOWORLD:&SESSION.:::P3_OUTPUT:&P1_INPUT.') The P3_OUTPUT text field on the popup page is set to 'Always, replacing any existing value in session state' and the type: 'Static Assignment', Session State: 'Per Session'.

Comment: `javascript:popupURL('f?p=&APP_ID.:HELLOWORLD:&SESSION.:::P3_OUTPUT:&P1_INPUT.') `

Comment: ah, i see now. Shoot. There is a semi-colon missing! `f?p=&APP_ID.:HELLOWORLD:&SESSION.::::P3_OUTPUT:&P1_INPUT.`